# A bullet fired on a glass pane makes a small hole in it while a stone breaks it completely. Give an accurate reason

Tags: forces, momentum

A bullet fired on a glass pane makes a small hole in it while a stone breaks it completely. Give an accurate reason.
Should the answer be due to inertia or due to high momentum or something else?

Comment: This question could be on topic and receive attention if it included a meaningful explanation of the thoughts you have so far, and why you are having trouble.